# Get the n-th record of a table, in order of its insertion

Tags: sql-server

I am importing data from Excel into a SQL Server 2016 database using the SQL Server Import & Export Data feature. After that I need to address the 1st and 3rd record to retrieve specific information (that the Data Dump of our ERP places there). The order criteria should be that of the time the record had been inserted in the table.

I know that this officially does not exist, but I wonder why the table is always displayed in the same order if you do not specify an order, so somewhere - internally (?) - there must be that information stored.

I don't see where to place a autoincrementing primary key during importing the data. That would solve the problem too.

It even looks good if I add a dummy order criteria (order by 1) but I don't know if that is reliable.

I will do the following, gambling that this will work always. Though I can't use "order by 1" in the row_number expression, I define a parameter and then its accepted.

```
declare @n int = 1
select * from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @n) as ord from ImportedData)x
where ord = 3
```

Comment: How do you import from excel into database?

Comment: Usually, for this kind of request, you'd add an auto-increment ID column and use that. Other than that, you could probably get the 'n-th' row by using 'LIMIT'.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: from Management Studio. Right click on the db, Task - Import Data. That activates the SQL Import Export Wizard

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: This is exactly what I was looking for as described: adding an autoincrementing ID during the import process. But I don't see this in the SQL Import Export Wizard. Limit just limits the amount of records returned but according to what order criteria.

Comment: Can't you simply add a column in excel and fill it with series starting from 1? Another idea could  be to get that data via a datareader (say using C#) and then inserting into SQL server using SqlBulkCopy. DataReader would read sequentially and the inserted table could have an identity field.

Comment: Why you need to add an  auto-increment ID column during import? Create a table, add that column and the others and then start the import and do the mapping in the wizard. The id-column will be populated automatically.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The EXCEL that I am importing from has an unpredictable amount of columns. The import is done into a table that the import Wizard creates. I am not importing into a specific table that I can design in the forehand.

Comment: Just avoid the import "wizard", even when it works, it's a gamble every day. There are a bunch of libs for java, C#, python and probably fortran that can traverse excel files and import them in order and where you control everything.

Comment: You can add identity column after import operation  in  table, that the import Wizard creates. I see, this identity column suitable for your requests - Get the n-th record of a table, in order of its insertion

Comment: @ValNik that's not guaranteed correct order though (even though you will probably get it 99/100)

Comment: @Barnabeck, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@TRANCOUNT)` instead of declaring variable to create a pseudo-correct row_number

Comment: If your data in excel doesn't have an existing column to determine the 'order of insertion' such as a createdDateTime field, then probably its order is not so much important? If it is, then SqlBulkCopy approach still works. You could 'create the table' using just maybe the first header line and do the import. It is simple than it sounds to be. I honestly did never use import wizard so I am not sure if that is practical like a magic to do what you want.

Comment: @siggemannen, I think, this will probably get 9999/10000 reliability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "gamble", here's your explanation: Usually SQL Server will write the data serially to a disk. It will also usually retrieve them in the same order when you `select` them without `order by`.

Gambling is, of course, bad practice. You are the judge of whether the convenience it provides is worth the probability of things going south and the designer appearing incompetent. It's a mindset, as well - as a database designer, in my opinion, you should strive more for "correct" and less for "easy", potentially making people dissatisfied in the short run - no one is going thank you for something that DIDN'T break because of good practices.

Comment: Off course I do not wan't to gamble. Thank you for clarifying the dynamics of the record inserting, that confirms what I expected, although it does not help to find a reliable solution. I guess I would need to add a column to the EXCEL before importing the data to set the order. But it's a rather ugly solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to add a sequence number to the table that populates as part of the insert.

> I don't see where to place a autoincrementing primary key during importing the data.

Depending on how you've set this up, you could do it ahead of time by adding the column in Excel, or by changing the table definition to add an identity column or other column using the `next value` in a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as the default value, or some combination thereof.

---

> I know that this officially does not exist

Correct. **THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS INSERTION ORDER!**

> ... but I wonder why the table is always displayed in the same order if you do not specify an order

Because you've been **lucky**. Without an `ORDER BY`, the database can **and will** show records in a different order from one run of *the same query* to the next, and there are **many** reasons this can happen. To name a few:

- Taking advantage of another similar query already in progress to share page reads, meaning your query could start partway through the expected order and then cycle back to the "beginning" to finish when the other query ends
- Taking advantage of some pages of the table that are already in RAM **now** while earlier pages are still loading
- Adding or changing an index
- Joining to a table or similar on a different key, making it more convenient to show records from this table differently
- Physically changing how the rows are stored on disk, which can happen after things like inserts later on, filling up (and then splitting) pages, changing the primary key, shrinking the table, etc
- Running a query that can be fulfilled entirely from an index with a different order
- ... and more

Most of these things are *uncommon*, but any one could surprise you at an inopportune moment.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to point out the risks of what I'm doing. As I use the SQL Import/Export data wizard, there is no option to generate an autoincrementing primary Key ID in the target table that gets created dynamically. It has been said that the Wizard is a crappy tool, but I don't know alternatives in SQL. I build a semi automated process to extract data from about 70 Excels with different structures and adding an extra Column to create the incremented ID hinders my process. The query is only called once, and if I don't hit the correct 3rd record I will notice from the results.